# Explaining to a child the issues of inappropriate content and helping them pick cleaner games? Comforting a child after having to take away an Item?

Tags: communication, video-games, presents

My child got a video game from a friend's parent as a "gift". I didn't know what was in the game until we turned it on. For the first few minutes the game looked ok but later got dirty content including blood, gore, drug use, sexual assault, and murder.

My child is only 8 and has not ever been exposed to any of the above or even educated about sexual content at all much less sexual assault. When I told her she can't play this game and that I was taking it away she got really upset and thought I was punishing her. I'm not but she doesn't understand and keeps thinking she's in trouble.

I need her to know that this is not a punishment as she has done nothing wrong but this is for her own safety as such content can be bad for her. I wanted to take her to pick out a new game that's cleaner and more appropriate. What can I do? How can I make her understand that she's not in trouble it's just a really dirty game and I want her to play something that's more family friendly?

Comment: Welcome to the group, Marnie!  I removed the toddler tag because you say your child is 8 and I don't see a second younger child of a toddler age mentioned.  If you feel that tag is indeed relevant, feel free to add it back.

Comment: Also consider to have a talk to the friend's parent who gave this inappropriate gift to your child.

Comment: Hi, Marnie, I've edited your post to make it easier to read. Please check it to make sure I haven't messed anything up. If I have then click the little "edit" below the tags to change it back.

Comment: Details of the PEGI rating scheme are here: https://pegi.info/what-do-the-labels-mean

Comment: Why have you put quotes around "gift"? Do you think this person has an ulterior motive or something? It certainly sounds pretty dubious to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a challenging conversation to be sure, but hopefully it's not the first time you've talked about appropriateness of things with the child - by 8, you should be expecting her to *regularly* encounter material other parents may consider appropriate but you do not (regardless of how permissive you are).

The core element of the conversation needs to be helping her understand *why* and *how* content might be inappropriate. When we have this discussion with our children (around the same age as yours), we talk about a few concepts.

- Content might be too *scary*.  We explain how games can be scary, and can be scary in ways that they will *enjoy* when they are older, but aren't old enough to appreciate now.  This also includes violence - we don't want them to play violent games, because they aren't able yet to fully differentiate fantasy from reality as compared to an adult.
- Content they might not understand.  This would include sexual content, for example.  We explain that some games include topics they don't understand yet, because they're not *physically* ready to understand it yet.  Another good example of this is a book with a romantic subplot - even without anything sexual, most 8 year olds simply *wouldn't get* why the characters acted how they did, and wouldn't be interested in it.
- Content we don't feel is safe for them.  The best example of this is a game with a chat feature.  We talk to them about how it is dangerous to talk to people online who you don't know, just how it is dangerous to talk to people in person you don't know.  Chatting can be harmless, and *usually* is, but there can be dangerous people who will take advantage of them.  We go into some detail here; we want to be the parents of the children who *identify* and *point out* the predator, and so we tell them in enough detail that they understand how a predator might act.

The focus here is *telling them why* in as much detail as possible, so that they not only understand why we are saying "not right now" but also in making sure they are equipped to make that decision for themselves as to whether this is a safe thing or not, when we're not there to oversee (at a friend's house, for example). Children can understand surprisingly difficult concepts, and if you have the conversation in a positive, productive tone, you would be surprised at how they will understand you.

The other thing we do is *always* play games with them before they can play by themselves - which serves two purposes.  One, it makes sure we know if a game is a problem or not; and two, it's a positive experience for them (who, at 8 or so, still are young enough to enjoy playing with Mom and Dad).  That way the next time they get a new game, they know what to do - ask us to play it with them!

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it look like it's your choice.

Most games include age ratings (for example PEGI for video-games), to help the parents choose the appropriate content.

So instead of trying to explain to your kid the reason **why** you are taking away the game (invite to negotiation), just show the age rating, and explain that is **a rule** that everyone should follow : she can play with this game when she will have the appropriate age.